# Django Rest Not Firing AJAX Success

Tags: jquery, ajax, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST APIView that takes a POST and patches an object:

```python
class TicketDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a snippet instance.
    """
    queryset = models.Ticket.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name='ticket.html'


    def get_object(self, pk):
        try: 
            return models.Ticket.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except models.Ticket.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        ticket = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = serializers.TicketSerializer(ticket)
        return Response({'ticket':ticket})  


    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):        
        ticket = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = serializers.TicketSerializer(ticket, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(request.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def post(self, request, pk, format=None):       
        ticket = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = serializers.TicketSerializer(ticket, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'Success':'Success'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The POST method is called via a jQuery AJAX submission:

```js
  $('#change-status').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var status = $('select[name="status"]').val();
   console.log('working');
   console.log(status);
   $.ajax({
       dataType:'json',
    type: "POST",
    url: '/core/group/ticket/{{ ticket.id }}/',
    data: {
     'csrfmiddlewaretoken':'{{ csrf_token }}', 
     'status':status,
     },
    success: function() {
      alert('Yeah!');
    }
   });
  });
```

The POST request works and the object gets updated, but the AJAX success function isn't getting called.

I've tried changing the Response from the standard Response(request.data), Response(request.data, status=HTTP_200_OK), and as shown in the code above.

I cannot understandy why the success function isn't getting triggered.

Anyone have any leads that might point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

The issue was that I had to include JSONRenderer in the APIView renderer_classes list in order for a non-HTML reponse to be returned.

```js
class TicketDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a snippet instance.
    """
    queryset = models.Ticket.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer]
```